# Google earth in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, google-earth

I was using Google earth in 11.10 without problems.  I recently upgraded to 12.04 with a clean install. machine is Acer core i3 2nd Gen. with 6gb ram. install is 64bit version. I am unable to run Google earth as it freezes the system in 5 seconds after starting the program. I tried solutions posted in omg Ubuntu for the ugly fonts problem with Google earth. the ugly fonts were resolved but the program freeze was not. Is there any solution?  level is beginner with Ubuntu.

Comment: This should be [reported as a bug in Google Earth](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/list?q=label:Type-Defect). (Make sure to search first, as it may have already been reported.)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and according to this bug report

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/975689

it is connected with the kernel and the Intel cpu. Fix seems to be committed and should come with the updates.

Comment: Note that bug report is a dupe of https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/966631.  Also note that a fix has been released for this.